# $routeParams not defined. I am not sure what I changed to make it not work suddenly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am not sure what is going on here.

```
 angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'myApp.controllers',
        'myApp.filters',
        'myApp.services',
        'myApp.directives'
    ]).
        config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/homepage',
                    controller: 'MyCtrl1'
                }).
                when('/about/:id', {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/'+$routeParams.id,
                    controller: 'MyCtrl1'
                }).
                when('/funnel', {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/funnel',
                    controller: 'MyCtrl2'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });
```

No matter if I browse to / or /about/:id  I get $routeParams is undefined.

Comment: WHat exactly are you trying to do? Dynamic templateUrl?

Comment: Yes. I have included ngRoute but for some reason the variable is not getting recognized and throwing an error even with I browse to the home page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject `$routeParams` service to use it. However in your case looks like you want to dynamically determine the template based on the routeparam. You cannot directly do it in the config phase of the app, which runs only once as a part of app initialization stage (and also you can inject `$routeParams` in the config phase of the app since there is no such provider). You you may want to look for a way to retrieve dynamic template and in order to support this angular provides this facility to use function as `templateUrl` to be able to dynamically determine the template url based on any routeparameters (which will be argument in the function).

You can do it this way:-

```
           when('/about/:id', {
                templateUrl: function(routeParam){ //register it as function
                    return '/partials/' + routeParam.id;  //Get the id from the argument
                },
                controller: 'MyCtrl1'
            }).
```

Right from [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

> templateUrl – **{string=|function()=}** – path or function that returns a path to an html template that should be used by ngView.
>   If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following parameters:
>   **`{Array.<Object>}`** - route parameters extracted from the current $location.path() by applying the current route

Comment: This worked for me.  I found so many different ways it was a bit confusing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line:

```
templateUrl: '/partials/'+$routeParams.id,
```

You're using `$routeParams` without every declaring or injecting it. If you add it to the params your function accepts, your page should stop throwing that error:

```
config(function ($routeProvider, $routeParams, $locationProvider) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If I add $routeParams like that in the config I get

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParams